# Create single push notification channel for multiple apps

Tags: azure, push, uwp, azure-mobile-services

For sending and receiving push notifications I want to register all my apps to the push channel with:

```
var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

I can now send and recieve pushes over this channel.

The problem is that this channel is only valid for one app. If I install the same app on another device I only receive the message on the same device as I sent it.

How can I push the notification to all my devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push channel is unique for each app installation. You can only use it to send a push to this one installation. If you want to send push to all the devices running your app, you have to collect the push channel info somewhere (your server, etc.) or you can use a service like https://parse.com/ that offer targeting multiple devices at once.

Comment: This is what I thought. I've tried parse but they didn't update wo windows 10

Comment: I found this but don't get how it knows which tags to send the notification to.  "Devices can specify one or more tags when registering with a Notification Hub, These tags don’t need to be pre-provisioned or disposed, and provide a very easy way for apps to send targeted notifications to millions of devices with a single API call, without you having to implement your own per-device notification routing infrastructure" - https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/09/16/delivering-push-notifications-to-millions-of-devices-with-windows-azure-notification-hubs/#mQppyhpwaEAcMehc.97

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install the same `debug-based` app on more than one device?
I believe that the channel is based on some identity of the app, so try to `release` it and I prefer you to create a store-based `hidden` app and test it..

The code you're writing is OK with millions of devices :)

Comment: I just finished uploading to the store and testing. Still same behaviour.

Comment: After registering. How do you send the Push from your UWP-App?

Answer (score 0):

According to this article,

Devices can specify one or more tags when registering with a Notification Hub, These tags don’t need to be pre-provisioned or disposed, and provide a very easy way for apps to send targeted notifications to millions of devices with a single API call, without you having to implement your own per-device notification routing infrastructure - https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/09/16/delivering-push-notifications-to-millions-of-devices-with-windows-azure-notification-hubs/#mQppyhpwaEAcMehc.97

In your Windows Store app, using the Windows Store device SDK, you can register to your Notification Hub simply calling

```
await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri, new string[] { "myTag", "myOtherTag" });
```

And then you can have your .NET backend broadcast a message to all your clients, just by calling

```
var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Hello everybody!</text></binding></visual></toast>";

await hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
```